# Netty. Is channel after successful bootstrap.connect an active channel?

Tags: java, netty, channel

I'm wondering, if after  successful bootstrap.connect() a channel is an active channel.

```
ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(HOST, PORT);
if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
   //is channelFuture.channel() active now?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is... once the connect operation completed successfully (be aware this is an async operation) the Channel is active until its closed.